# try catch not working in PHP

Tags: php, exception

I have the following code that is intended to run some code inside the try catch. However, when the `file_get_content` fails, it still doesnt go to the catch function but instead just continues running and shows more errors (for example at `property_exists` since `$weatherJson` is not defined.

```
   try{
        $weatherJson = file_get_contents("http://api.someApi?lat={$this->request->getParam("lon")}&lon={$this->request->getParam("lon")}&appid=abcdefg");
        $weatherJson = json_decode($weatherJson);
        if (property_exists($weatherJson, 'list')) {
            $result->weather = $weatherJson->list[0]->weather[0]->main;
            $result->timeStamp = $weatherJson->list[0]->dt_txt;
            return $result;
        } else {
            return "no results found";
        }
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        echo "something is wrong";

    }
```

Comment: `file_get_contents` doesn't throw exceptions

Comment: `try...catch` works only when an exception is thrown. `file_get_contents` does not throw an exception if it fails. From the manual `@return string The function returns the read data or false on failure.`

Comment: You should consider reading the manual

Comment: The manual also states that *"An E_WARNING level error is generated if filename cannot be found, maxlength is less than zero, or if seeking to the specified offset in the stream fails"* so you may get a result of `false` **and** a warning but still no exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `file_get_contents` doesn't throw exceptions, it returns `false` on failure. You could adjust your code to throw an exception yourself if it returns false though.

```
try {
    $weatherJson = @file_get_contents("http://api.someApi?lat={$this->request->getParam("lon")}&lon={$this->request->getParam("lon")}&appid=abcdefg");
    if (!$weatherJson) {
        throw new \Exception;
    }

    $weatherJson = json_decode($weatherJson);
    if (property_exists($weatherJson, 'list')) {
        $result->weather = $weatherJson->list[0]->weather[0]->main;
        $result->timeStamp = $weatherJson->list[0]->dt_txt;

        return $result;
    } else {
        return "no results found";
    }
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    echo "something is wrong";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but even when I add that exception I still get that Warning: file_get_contents with a 502 Bad Gateway, because I am supplying with wrong parameters in that API on purpose.. is there a way to hide that warning?

Comment: Yeah, you can suppress warnings by putting the `@` symbol before `file_get_contents` so it becomes `@file_get_contents('...');`. See my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) doesn't throw an exception.

> On failure, file_get_contents() will return FALSE.

Answer (score -1):

```
try{
        $weatherJson = file_get_contents("http://api.someApi?lat={$this->request->getParam("lon")}&lon={$this->request->getParam("lon")}&appid=abcdefg");
        $weatherJson = json_decode($weatherJson);
        if (property_exists($weatherJson, 'list')) {
            $result->weather = $weatherJson->list[0]->weather[0]->main;
            $result->timeStamp = $weatherJson->list[0]->dt_txt;
            return $result;
        } else {
            return "no results found";
        }
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        echo "something is wrong";

    }
```

there \ in your catch, delete it

Comment: Actually, because of the file hierarchy I have in the project, I do need that back slash.

Comment: should add validation for your $weatherJson, did not need for try catch then if($weatherJson)